# Could NOT find FLTK (missing: FLTK_INCLUDE_DIR)

Tags: c++, cmake, fltk

I'm trying to use fltk library in my project but I have some troubles. 
Here is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(pp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)


add_executable(pp main.cpp)

FIND_PACKAGE(FLTK REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(GTK REQUIRED)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(pp ${FLTK_LIBRARIES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(pp ${GTK_LIBRARIES})
```

FLTK version: **1.3.4**

Cmake version: **3.7.2**

I have installed fltk library in my /usr/local dirs

Include files are located in /usr/local/include/FL

I saw that the FindFLTK.cmake looks for following files: 
FL/Fl.h or FL/Fl.H which the FL/Fl.h is located in /usr/local/include/FL so it can be found.

Here is the error message:

> > Could NOT find FLTK (missing: FLTK_INCLUDE_DIR)

Have you any ideas to solve this problem?

**UPDATE**

Current version of CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7.2)
project(pp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)


add_executable(pp main.cpp)

target_include_directories(pp PRIVATE /usr/local/include/FL)

set (LIBRARIES fltk Xrender Xcursor Xfixes Xext Xft fontconfig Xinerama pthread dl m  X11)


message(STATUS mess: ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

target_link_libraries(pp ${LIBRARIES})'
```

In this configuration I can compile, and link executable, but why configuration with FIND_PACKAGE does not work? Where I should look for a bug?

Comment: Please, show also the exact error message about finding FLTK.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Not to state the obvious but have you tried setting FLTK_INCLUDE_DIR ?

Comment: @PeterT: The variable `FLTK_INCLUDE_DIR` is described in the module [FindFLTK.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/module/FindFLTK.html)  as a *result* variable, but not as a variable which can be assigned by a user. So one should NOT set `FLTK_INCLUDE_DIR` explicitely. (Such setting could be ignored, may break the script, may work, but only for specific versions,... - in other words, setting the variable leads to **undefined behavior**).

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: In working example, include directory `/usr/local/include/FL` looks suspicious. Normally, system-wide installation places its headers in a way, so `/usr/local/include` can be used as an include directory. What is the **exact path** to the file `Fl.h`, `/usr/local/include/FL/FL/Fl.h` or `/usr/local/include/FL/Fl.h`?

Comment: The second one - /usr/local/include/FL/Fl.H

Answer (score 0):

Probably bad installation of library. I just installed fresh one from GitHub sources with CMake configuring by `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" .` with followed `make` and `make install` to install it in compiler library I suppose.

After that errors containing `Could NOT find FLTK (missing: FLTK_INCLUDE_DIR)` has disappeared in compilation of another project. I suppose, cmake error report is not so strict and clarified, i.e. this error means some exception in `FindFLTK.cmake` and not exactly about missing `FLTK_INCLUDE_DIR`.